# youtube video in android without hardware acceleration

Tags: android, html, youtube, cordova, icenium

I have an application that i am developing in ICENIUM Mist for a blog, which plays youtube videos inside the application using . Currently i can get the videos to playing when Hardware Acceleration is on but the problem with this is that it affects the quality of the applications. It makes images in the applications blurry and also shows white screen during transitions to deferent screens. So this requires me to turn Hardware Acceleration off but when Hardware Acceleration is off i can only hear the audio from the video while no picture/video showing just a black screen. What other solution is there to resolving this problem?

I have tried using phongap video plugin but with that it opens the video in the youtube application i don't want to have to take the users into another application. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this by using the translate3d transform method. Here is a sample:

```
.testClass {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

}

```
<div class="testClass">
<iframe width="100%" height="58%" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0pVbav71wQo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I have tried this on my note 2 device I couldn't get it to play bit when I tried on Samsung s3 it works fine

Comment: I would not bet my app tests on a Samsung device, try a clean Android. Samsung often modify the webview to fit their "vision".Plus,since it plays the audio, you should be able to put the video in full screen where it would use the utube app and work.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest iframes but they are not fully supported in icenium, if you are still having problems, maybe you could open the video in an in-app browser ?

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('http://anythingyouwant.com)"></a>
```

This is just a suggestion for you if worst comes to worst and you cannot improve the quality of the blog.